# Using TeXGyreSchola-Regular and xelatex get "Font shape `EU1/qcs/m/n' undefined"

Tags: junicode, undefined

With this TeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tgschola}
    \setmainfont{TeXGyreSchola-Regular}[
      BoldFont = {TeXGyreSchola-Bold},
      ItalicFont = {TeXGyreSchola-Italic},
      BoldItalicFont = {TeXGyreSchola-BoldItalic},
      Ligatures = TeX,
    ]
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
    \begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=qcs,fontsize=\relscale{1.1}]
        This is some verbatim text.
    \end{Verbatim}
    This is some verbatim text. (for comparison)\\
    This is some regular text.
\end{document}
```

Compilation with XeLaTeX gives in the TeXShop console output:

> ```
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/qcs/m/n' undefined
> (Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.
> ```

The log file gives the suggestion:

> ```
> LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+qcs on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Info:    No file EU1qcs.fd. on input line 11.
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/qcs/m/n' undefined
> (Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.
> ```

I have reinstalled the font in my home directory texmf tree (Mac Yosemite TeXLive). Using autoinst I tried to create `EU1qcs.fd`, but it creates four files (some defaults taken):

- EU1TeXGyreSchola-LF.fd,
- EU1TeXGyreSchola-OsF.fd,
- EU1TeXGyreSchola-TLF.fd, and
- EU1TeXGyreSchola-TOsF.fd.

I have not found the incantation to generate `EU1qcs.fd`. I am using the Gyre fonts for cost and easy reading for a genealogy book I am writing. The `fancyvrb` stuff is to achieve a specific goal for the book, and is not strictly needed for this example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't load tgschola. It is not meant for xelatex/fontspec.

Comment: OK, did not know that. I thought it was a unicode font so needed fontspec. So the recommendation is to use regular latex and an encoding for TeXGyreSchola that works with fontenc, so the appropriate one of the various *qcs.fd files would prevent this type of problem?

Comment: Depends what you want. Either (pdf)latex + tgschola + fontenc, or xe/lualatex + fontspec + your \setmainfont command.

Comment: pdflatex works fine; unicode not needed for anything I envision at this time. Thank you.  In three sentences, problem solved. I've been trying to fix this for a week.

Comment: Is there anything I should do to rate this response? Total newbie here.

Comment: I made my comment in an answer. You can check/vote this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tgschola` is not meant for xelatex.

Use either the engine (pdf)latex + `\usepackage{tgschola}` + `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

or xelatex/lualatex + `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{...}`.